# PHP expression "and-statement"?

Tags: php, expression

I have this csv file which has 2 rows. 
The first one shows the city name and 2nd shows a number (statistic)

Example:

```
[City]        [Count of dogs]
[Los Angeles] [100]
[New York]    [-]
```

Now my problem is that I don't want to show the city's and the statistic from it that have `[-]` as `[Count of dogs]`.

This is what I've tried right now:

```
    <?php
    echo"<table border='1'>";
    if (($handle = fopen("table.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ";")) !== FALSE) {
            echo "<tr>";
            $num = count($data);
            for ($i=0; $i < $num; $i++) {
                $string = $data[$i];
                $m = preg_match("#\w{2,}#", $string, $match); 
                if ($m) { 
                        echo "<td>". $data[$i];
                     $m = preg_match("#\d{2}#", $string, $match); 
                     if ($m) { 
                        echo $data[$i] . "<br /> </td>";
                     }  
                } 
            }
            echo"</tr>";
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    echo"</table>";

?>
```

It doesn't show the "-" right now but it does show the city, I was wondering if a "and-statement" exist for expressions, or is there a different way to do this?

Picture of how it looks right now: [IMG]http://i59.tinypic.com/14sl4xg.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: How does the $data[$i] look?

Comment: $data[$i] is everything in the csv file, like the example.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the HTML generated by the above code?

Comment: By $data[$i] I meant what string it is. BTW, why do you echo $data[$i] twice

Comment: Hi, I've added the picture of how it looks like, don't know how to add csv files with jsfiddle.

@user2781994 I have put it twice one for the first expression check (more then 2 words) and the 2nd one check if it contains 2 numbers so not "-"

Answer (score 0):

IS it just "-"?  Then you can check for it...

```
 while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    if ($data[1] != "-") {
       echo "<tr>";
       ....
       echo "</tr>";
    }
 }
```

Comment: No my CSV has more then 1 "-" in it.

Comment: I mean that "dogs" field.  The above code will branch around that entire row if that field == "-", and only draw the row if it != "-".

Answer (score 0):

Check the occurrences of `-` in the second column using [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function. If the second column doesn't contain any `-`, then print the row

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    if (strpos($data[$num-1],'-') === false) {
        echo "<tr>";
        for ($i=0; $i < $num; $i++) {
            $string = $data[$i];
            $m = preg_match("#\w{2,}#", $string, $match); 
            if ($m) { 
                    echo "<td>". $data[$i];
                 $m = preg_match("#\d{2}#", $string, $match); 
                 if ($m) { 
                    echo $data[$i] . "<br /> </td>";
                 }  
            } 
        }
        echo"</tr>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, this solution gives actually the same result :(.

Answer (score 0):

If, count of dog field is the filtering field, then take that field first before display,

Here I have checked for numeric, because the count of dog is always in numeric, You may use any other logic as you have done using preg_match,

```
 <?php
 while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ";")) !== FALSE) {
if(is_numeric($data[1])) {
//proceed your logic here
}
else {
continue;//to go for the next row
}
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your CSV looks like your example, you can skip the rows where "Number of Dogs" is a dash.

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    if( $data[1] == '-' ) {
        continue;
    }
    echo "<tr>";
    // ...
}
```

Or if the dash can also be any other non-number:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    if( !is_numeric($data[1]) ) {
        continue;
    }
    echo "<tr>";
    // ...
}
```

Also, I don't know what the other `if` checks are for, but it looks to me you want to just `echo` the data

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    if( $data[1] == '-' ) {
        continue;
    }
    echo "<tr>";
    $num = count($data);
    for ($i=0; $i < $num; $i++) {
        echo "<td>" . $data[$i] . "</td>";
    }
    echo"</tr>";
}
```